# Castle Active Record can not execute query because table name is equal to a keyword

Tags: sql-server, castle-activerecord

I am trying to do the "getting started" from Castle Active record, now I got into this problem could not execute query exception

select count(*) as col_0_0_ from User user0_ where 1=1
//it's SQL Server 2008

question: Can I somehow make castle put the table name into [] like [User]?

Comment: you can defintely to this (illustrated below by Patrick), but you almost certainly want your table to be named "Users" instead of "User" (assuming you CAN name your table, and you're not hooking into some other source).  

Each row in your table represents an individual "user," and the entire table represents your "users."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [ActiveRecord] attribute, you can define the name of the table.  Example:

```
[ActiveRecord("[User]")]
public class User : ActiveRecordBase<User>
```